# What kind of photons would antimatter make?

Tags: waves, photons, electrons, antimatter

Would we be able to see antimatter photons? Does antimatter photon rotate backward making even the light that comes in contact with the with antimatter electrons react adversely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is founded on a misconception.

There aren't two kinds of photons. There are just photons. Experiments with antimatter have been going on for decades, and it makes photons. Just plain old photons.

Heck just recently we read about a big advance in the spectroscopy of antimatter atoms.

Comment: Unlike the (possible) situation with neutrinos changing the spin of a photon does not change it's character. Matter can emit photons of either helicity as can antimatter. This is one of those places where jumping around gets you into trouble. You are missing a large fraction of the basic database of facts and methods you need to be able to do physics (or even talk about physics).

Comment: I'm trying to clean up some poor questions. Can you delete this so I can?

Comment: Despite the negative reaction it received I see this question as naive rather than bad, and I think that it is not unreasonable to image that other users will find it when searching in the future.